# llvm, defining strings and arrays via c++ API

Tags: c++, llvm

I develop a toy compiler, and trying to implement strings and arrays.
I have noticed that clang creates always a global variable for those types, even if they where defined within a function.
I guess that there is a good reason for that, so I try to do the same.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to do it via c++ API.
[kalidoscope tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl01.html) does not cover strings and arrays, so the only source that I have found is [the documentation](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html).

In the documentation for the Module class, there is the function [getOrInsertGlobal](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a1ec20a6f23ced1a328d4b1223fa22d96), which looks relevant, but I cannot understand how I set the actual value of the global. The function arguments include only the name and the type of the variable. So where does the value go?

So the question is: how can I define a global string, such as "hello" or array, such as [i32 1, i32 2] in llvm c++ API? Any example would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is called a read-only [GlobalVariable](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables) and you need that variable, an initializer, and probably a [constant cast](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions) so that all of your strings can have the same type.

Suppose your strings are the C kind — null-terminated sequences of bytes. In that case you'll want your strings to be an array of zero bytes, so that all arrays have the same type. But the initialisers need to be arrays of the right numbers of bytes, so that each initialiser's type will match its value. So you create your array using something like this (cut and pasted together from bits of code I've written, won't even compile, is not the most efficient way, but does contain most of the building blocks you need):

```
std::vector<llvm::Constant *> chars(utf8string.size());
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < utf8string.size(); i++)
  chars[i] = ConstantInt::get(i8, utf8string[i]);
auto init = ConstantArray::get(ArrayType::get(i8, chars.size()),
                               entries);
GlobalVariable * v = 
  new GlobalVariable(module, init->getType(), true,
                     GlobalVariable::ExternalLinkage, init,
                     utf8string);
return ConstantExpr::getBitCast(v, i8->getPointerTo());
```

Note that a GlobalVariable is a pointer to whatever it's been initialised as, so if you initialise it with the five-byte sequence "test\0", then it'll be a pointer to a five bytes. Or, if you cast, it can be a pointer to 0 bytes (LLVM lets you index past the official end), or it can be an instance if an abstract type you define.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I implemented the value-building part. It looks like working great. I still do not really get how can I insert the global declaration to the module, now that I have the value. Can you please explain this part to me?

Comment: The module is responsible for emitting the globals (to a .bc file, an executable or an in-memory JITted result), so it has to know about all of the functions, constant strings and everything else. The GlobalVariable() constructor will register the newly created object using the supplied name, which needs to be unique. That's all, I think. (BTW, you're supposed to mark answers as accepted if etc. An orange tickmark, I think.)

Comment: Ok, I see! Just one more point on your code. Are we responsible to delete the object you create with new above, or will the destructor of ConstantExpr will?
Sorry for asking many questions, I am not a C++ expert and I struggle not to do a mess with the memory management. Until now, I never called new for llvm types, only the get___() functions from the module, type etc.

Comment: The object has to live for as long as the Module does. I don't remember whether the Module will delete it, or perhaps the Context, or whether you have to. But you definitely cannot delete anything more than the std::vector<> before the Module is deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Using the code and the help of @arnt on the answer above, and I ended up with the following code to implement a string initialization. It now works, and also avoids the call to new, so it does not require any cleanup later.

I post it, hoping that it may be useful for someone.

```
llvm::Value* EulStringToken::generateValue(llvm::Module* module, llvm::LLVMContext context) {
    //0. Defs
    auto str = this->value;
    auto charType = llvm::IntegerType::get(context, 8);


    //1. Initialize chars vector
    std::vector<llvm::Constant *> chars(str.length());
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
      chars[i] = llvm::ConstantInt::get(charType, str[i]);
    }

    //1b. add a zero terminator too
    chars.push_back(llvm::ConstantInt::get(charType, 0));


    //2. Initialize the string from the characters
    auto stringType = llvm::ArrayType::get(charType, chars.size());

    //3. Create the declaration statement
    auto globalDeclaration = (llvm::GlobalVariable*) module->getOrInsertGlobal(".str", stringType);
    globalDeclaration->setInitializer(llvm::ConstantArray::get(stringType, chars));
    globalDeclaration->setConstant(true);
    globalDeclaration->setLinkage(llvm::GlobalValue::LinkageTypes::PrivateLinkage);
    globalDeclaration->setUnnamedAddr (llvm::GlobalValue::UnnamedAddr::Global);



    //4. Return a cast to an i8*
    return llvm::ConstantExpr::getBitCast(globalDeclaration, charType->getPointerTo());
}
```